How to set Orange database management system options (load tool)
I am using the Orange database management system.
(Refer to what you see in the image) When you command a regular sql statement and view the parsed table, the table looks good.
However, when using the load tool or viewing the list of recently executed queries as a chart (=table) using the F8 key, the data is not displayed properly because the text is larger than the table cell size.
I would like to know how to increase the table cell height (see red highlight in image)
Can I find out how?
The way I did it was
I found an option settings tab called ‘tools > orange options’ within the orange program.
There are a lot of settings tabs, so I don't know which one will solve the problem.

The way I did it was
I found an option settings tab called ‘tools > orange options’ within the orange program.
There are a lot of settings tabs, so I don't know which one will solve the problem.

Please DONT SPAM TAGS. If you are using Orange, I assume you are not using Oracle and MySQL as well

You may have to operate a trial and error senario. Change one param (that looks promising) and see what it does. If not the right one, repace the original value and try another

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
